# Let $f : \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function satisfying $\int_{o}^{x} f(t)dt = xf(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}.$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm studying for an exam I'm taking in a few months and I came across this question:

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function satisfying

$$\int_{0}^{x} f(t)dt = xf(x) \ \text{for all} \ x \in \mathbb{R}$$

Knowing $f(3) = 5$, determine $f(-3)$.

My initial idea was to show that g(x) = $\int_{o}^{x} f(t)dt = xf(x)$ is an even or odd function but I was unsuccessful. I also tried to apply the fundamental theorem of calculus but I came across the following problem: $g'(x) = f(x) = xf'(x) + f(x)$.

Any suggestions or tips on how to get out of this problem?

Comment: Why do you believe it is wrong?

Comment: @Henry It was carelessness on my part. In a few moments I will correct it.

Comment: When I posted my answer, the author's edit in bold ("the following argument") was not present. I realise my answer looks redundant now that that edit is present

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: it follows that $x\cdot f'(x)$ is zero for all $x$. In particular, $f'(x)$ is zero whenever $x\neq0$.

Comment: You would need to carefully argue "$f$ must be constant though". It's not a direct implication, "$f'(x)$ when $x\neq0$ therefore $f$ is constant", probably at the level of this exam a few intermediate logical steps would be expected

Comment: I had thought of using that argument but ended up leaving it there. Thanks for your comment.

Comment: @FShrike On the intervals On the intervals $(-\infty, 0)$ and $(0, \infty)$, $f'$ is zero so $f$ is constant on those intervals. By hypothesis, $f$ is differentiable so it's continuous, so it must be the same constant, so $f$ is constant on all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @DavidLui That's right. (and the mean value theorem / inequality allows you to get the claim $f$ is constant on each of $(-\infty,0),(0,\infty)$)

Comment: @DavidLui A different approach would be this; by "Darboux's theorem", derivatives satisfy the intermediate value property. If $f'(0)\neq0$, then because $f'([0,1])$ contains the two distinct points $0,f'(0)$ it must contain all points inbetween the two; there must be some points in $x\in(0,1)$ with $f'(x)\neq0$ but this is a contradiction